# MySQL Order By in Subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve this problem on [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sql-projects/problem):

Input (Projects table)

[image]

Output:

2015-10-28 2015-10-29
2015-10-30 2015-10-31
2015-10-13 2015-10-15
2015-10-01 2015-10-04

So what the problem is asking for is to treat consecutive end dates as part of one project and return the start and end dates of projects ordered by the date differences in ascending order. As you can see from the above example, tasks 1,2,3 are the in the same project, tasks 4,5 are in the same project and tasks 7 and 8 are their own projects.

This is one of the solutions I found:

```sql
set @sdate = null;
set @nextdate = null;

select sd, max(ed) ed2
from (
    select if(@nextdate = start_date,  @sdate, @sdate := start_date) as sd,
           @nextdate := end_date as ed
    from Projects 
    order by start_date
) tmp
group by sd
order by datediff(max(ed), sd)
```

It is using variables to store the previous end date and compare it to the current row, but I'm confused by the `order by` clause in the subquery:

1. If I take out the 'order by start_date' in the subquery, the result it returns will be wrong -- I was under the impression that in MySQL the ordering of subqueries is ignored?
2. My understanding was that order by is executed after the select so here it would be ordering the results from select in the subquery, but it seems like it's actually ordering the source table (Properties) *before* the select statement -- am I correct?

Could someone help me understand why this is the case? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is necessary for the variable assignment to work. This is similar to the idea of assigning row numbers in older MySQL version. When you run:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Projects;
```

Without the `ORDER BY`, you'll get almost every `Start_date` value in ascending order except for the `Start_date` of `2015-11-04` until `2015-11-07` which gives you result in this order:

```
...
ID  Start_date  End_date
16  2015-11-04  2015-11-05
10  2015-11-07  2015-11-08
15  2015-11-06  2015-11-07
11  2015-11-05  2015-11-06
...
```

It start from 4 but then the next one is 7,6 then 5. This breaks the variable assignment. If you run the query like this:

```
 SELECT *,IF(@nextdate = start_date,  @sdate, @sdate := start_date) AS sd,
           @nextdate := end_date AS ed
    FROM Projects;
```

You can see the difference in the results where the `Start_date` is in the correct order vs with the incorrect order:

```
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID  | Start_date |  End_date  |     sd     |     ed     |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   1 | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-02 | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-02 |
|  24 | 2015-10-02 | 2015-10-03 | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-03 |
|   2 | 2015-10-03 | 2015-10-04 | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-04 |
|  23 | 2015-10-04 | 2015-10-05 | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-05 |
   .......                                                 
|   3 | 2015-10-11 | 2015-10-12 | 2015-10-11 | 2015-10-12 |
|  22 | 2015-10-12 | 2015-10-13 | 2015-10-11 | 2015-10-13 |
   .......                                                 
|  16 | 2015-11-04 | 2015-11-05 | 2015-11-04 | 2015-11-05 |
|  10 | 2015-11-07 | 2015-11-08 | 2015-11-07 | 2015-11-08 |
|  15 | 2015-11-06 | 2015-11-07 | 2015-11-06 | 2015-11-07 |
|  11 | 2015-11-05 | 2015-11-06 | 2015-11-05 | 2015-11-06 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

With the subquery returning the result like above, whereby 3 of the rows should actually generate `sd=2015-11-04` but instead have different value, the outer query `GROUP BY` will then gave 14 rows of results. By adding the `ORDER BY Start_date` in the subquery, you'll get the result for `2015-11-04` until `2015-11-07` like this instead:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID | Start_date |  End_date  |     sd     |     ed     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 16 | 2015-11-04 | 2015-11-05 | 2015-11-04 | 2015-11-05 |
| 11 | 2015-11-05 | 2015-11-06 | 2015-11-04 | 2015-11-06 |
| 15 | 2015-11-06 | 2015-11-07 | 2015-11-04 | 2015-11-07 |
| 10 | 2015-11-07 | 2015-11-08 | 2015-11-04 | 2015-11-08 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

So, it's not actually the ordering that makes the answer wrong but it's the extra rows in the end result.

[Here's a fiddle to play around](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b527559d8466a8c92c7b6560568d806)

Comment: thank you for the answer, so my understand is that `order by` makes the input data in order so that the next row will either be a consecutive day or it won't, which makes the variable assignment depending on this condition work -- is that the right idea? Because the source table might not be in that order. if yes, then order by is executed before the select (the one in the subquery, which does the variable assignment) so it actually orders the Projects table first and then the select is run on top of that?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea and yes `order by` is executed before `select`.